# Temporal Join in python using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I need to compute a "temporal join" in python. I am using pandas for reading and working on the datasets. I have two datasets:

```
df:

TIME  some_features  LABEL
  1         f          -1
  2         f          -1
  3         f          -1
  5         f          -1
  6         f          -1
  7         f          -1
 10         f          -1
 11         f          -1
 13         f          -1
 15         f          -1

labelDf:

TIME_START  TIME_STOP  LABEL
  2          4           0
  6          8           1
  9         10           2
 11         14           1
```

The output of my script has to be the temporal join of df with labelDf, thus:

```
df:

TIME  some_features  LABEL
  1         f          -1
  2         f           0
  3         f           0
  5         f          -1
  6         f           1
  7         f           1
 10         f           2
 11         f           1
 13         f           1
 15         f          -1
```

Right now I am using a very simple function that basically has to look at each row for each of the two datasets:

```
def temporalJoin(df, labelDf, typeLabel):
    count = 0
    for index, row in labelDf.iterrows():
        for index2, row2 in df.iterrows():
            if(row2.TIME > row.TIME_START and row2.TIME < row.TIME_STOP):
                df.loc[index2, 'LABEL_'+typeLabel] = row.LABEL_START
                count = count +1
    print("Label counts: " + str(count) + "\n")
```

Running this code is extremely slow, and I need to run it multiple times for dataset that has a size greater than 2GB. As the dataset of the label is non-overlapping a good start is to break the loop when I match a label, however, I do not like this solution, and it does not really solve the problem as the initial dataset is larger than the label one.
The worst case will be a label file that contains a label for each timestamp in the initial dataset, so I am wondering if there is a way to select and run the join only for the rows that appear in the label dataset.

Thank you.

EDIT: I have modified the example to include two new details:

- the first thing is that the sequence of TIME does not have a fixed interval. Thus, it can happen that TIME = [1,2,3,5,8,11,13]
- secondly the label file is not binary, there can be un unpredictable number of labels

EDIT2:

- different intervals in labelDf can have the same label

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect this approach will be faster:

```
df.set_index('TIME', inplace=True)

df.update(labelDf.reset_index().melt(id_vars=['index', 'LABEL']). \
          groupby(['index', 'LABEL'])['value']. \
          apply(lambda x: pd.Series(list(range(*list(x))+[max(x)]))). \
          reset_index().set_index('value'))

df
#      some_features  LABEL
# TIME                     
# 1                f   -1.0
# 2                f    0.0
# 3                f    0.0
# 4                f    0.0
# 5                f   -1.0
# 6                f    1.0
# 7                f    1.0
```

**Explanation:**

This performs a series of reshaping operations on your `labelDf` (none of them in-place) before passing the reshaped dataframe to [`.update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.update.html).

First, melt `labelDf`:

```
labelDf.melt(id_vars='LABEL')
#    LABEL    variable  value
# 0      0  TIME_START      2
# 1      1  TIME_START      6
# 2      0   TIME_STOP      4
# 3      1   TIME_STOP      8
```

Then, group by `LABEL`, select `value`, and apply a lambda that places the `TIME_START` and `TIME_STOP` values in a list, creates a range with that list and appends the list max to make it inclusive (e.g. so `range(*list([2,4]))+[max([2,4])]` returns `[2, 3, 4]`), and passes the resulting list to `pd.Series` to split the list into columns. Hence the result of this operation:

```
labelDf.melt(id_vars='LABEL').groupby('LABEL')['value'].apply( \ 
   lambda x: pd.Series(range(*list(x))+[max(x)]))
```

...looks like this:

```
# LABEL   
# 0      0    2
#        1    3
#        2    4
# 1      0    6
#        1    7
#        2    8
```

The final steps are reseting the index, and then setting it to `value`, in this case, so that the dataframe that's passed to `.update` looks like this:

```
#        LABEL  level_1
# value                
# 2          0        0
# 3          0        1
# 4          0        2
# 6          1        0
# 7          1        1
# 8          1        2
```

Note that you can drop the `level_1` column, but it's not necessary -- since there is no column with this name in your `df`, it will have no bearing on the result of `update`.

Comment: Hi, running you solution gives that error: "range expected at most 3 arguments, got 10". I want to add one more thing, honestly, I have not completely understood your solution, however, anyway, the initial df is not a sequence of consequent observation, thus it may be that TIME can be 1,2,3,10,11,20.

Comment: @GuidoMuscioni that sounds like a relevant piece of information to include in your question. Why don't you revise your question to make it clearer what you're asking.

Comment: I have modified the example, sorry for the miss of some details.

Comment: Thanks @GuidoMuscioni. Are there any `LABEL` values in your `labelDf` that appear more than once? My hunch is that you received the error because the same `LABEL` appears in `labelDf` for multiple START + STOP time ranges.

Comment: Yes, It can happen. Sorry for that, as you can see my solution completely abstract from what the values are, thus, I am discovering these things now.

Comment: @GuidoMuscioni no worries, I tweaked the solution and it should now work, given that new info. I will still need to update the explanation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168960/discussion-between-guido-muscioni-and-cmaher).